# Google Fonts not loading on App Launch in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-font-api, google-fonts

I have added Internet Permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file. However, when my app launches, it's not downloading the relevant Google Font (varelaRound) and all widgets containing Text with GoogleFont TextStyle is not rendered, such as `Appbar`, `ListTile`, etc.

However, when I navigate to a different screen, all textual content display properly with varelaRound font and no problem occurs for all subsequent screens.

I would like to know the cause for this issue, since neither debugging nor running on release mode is yielding me any log that would help me understand the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass fontFamily param in MaterialApp to set the font-family for the entire app.

For example, in basic flutter app template application, if you would do

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.varelaRound().fontFamily,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
```

You will see the app font family is changed on app launch.

Comment: Did this, still the same problem persists.

Comment: Do you have any other Theme widget wrapped in the Scaffold of the home page?

Comment: No, just a regular scaffold.